# Keras: saving model defined as a class raises NotImplementedError

Tags: keras

I am writing this post after reading similar questions and answers that didn't work in my case. You may notice that I defined the input shape in the first layer.

I created a very small CNN in Keras, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
         self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 5, strides = (2,2), data_format = 'channels_first', input_shape = (3,224,224))
         self.bn1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1)
         self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
         self.globalavg = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format = 'channels_first')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = tf.keras.activations.relu(x)
        x = self.globalavg(x)

        return self.fc1(x)
```

Then I fed something into it and printed the result successfully (the weights are probably random at the moment, but that's ok):

```
image = tf.ones(shape = (1, 3, 224, 224))  # Defined "channels first" when created the layers
mynet = MyNet()
outputs = mynet(image)
print(tf.keras.backend.eval(outputs))
```

The result I saw at this step was the 10 outputs of the `fc1` layer:

```
[[-1.1747773  -0.21640654 -0.16266493 -0.44879064 -0.642066    0.78132695  -0.03920581 -0.30874395 -0.04169023 -0.10409291]]
```

Then I tried to save the model with its weights, by calling `mynet.save('mynet.hdf5')`, and got the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Currently `save` requires model to be a graph network. Consider using `save_weights`, in order to save the weights of the model.
```

Note that I am new to Keras and that most of my experience is with PyTorch.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update:

Following @ikibir's answer, I redefined the network as a sequential network:

```
myNetAsSeq = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
myNetAsSeq.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 5, strides = (2,2), data_format = 'channels_first', input_shape = (3,224,224)))
myNetAsSeq.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1))
myNetAsSeq.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
myNetAsSeq.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format = 'channels_first'))
myNetAsSeq.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))
```

This time calling `myNetAsSeq.save('mynet.hdf5')` succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about my answer but i believe you don't create a model you are just creating each layer individually, when you run 'call' function you just pass the variables to this layers.

In keras you should use

```
model = models.Sequential()
```

for create model and you should use

```
model.add()
```

to add layers

then you can save this model